# $(document).ready() when jQuery is loaded as a dynamically appended <script>

Tags: javascript, jquery

For reasons that are beyond my control I have to load jQuery via a dynamically appended `<script>` tag, and only do this upon some arbitrary event, *not* at page load.

My problem is in detecting the moment when jquery is ready, for the code below doesn't work:

```
(function(){
    var s=document.createElement('script');
    s.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    s.setAttribute('src','http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js');
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s);
})()

$(document).ready(function() {
  // something that uses jquery and currently doesn't work
});
```

How do I detect the moment when jquery is ready to be used in this particular configuration?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is the js fila always loaded dynamically?

Comment: Possible duplicate. Go check these questions: - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032721/async-load-javascript-files-with-callback - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249030/load-javascript-async-then-check-dom-loaded-before-executing-callback

Comment: How is dynamically loaded javascript file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `onload` and `onreadystatechange` event handlers:

```
var scr   = document.createElement('script'),
    head      = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

scr.onload = scr.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if( scr.readyState ){
            if(scr.readyState === 'complete' || scr.readyState === 'loaded'){
                scr.onreadystatechange = null;                                                  
                myReadyFunc();
            }
        } 
        else{                               
                myReadyFunc();          
        }
};  

head.insertBefore(scr, head.firstChild);

function myReadyFunc() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // something that uses jquery and currently doesn't work
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the `<script>` element's `onreadystatechange` event, and, if `this.readyState` is `complete` or `loaded`, run your function.
For Firefox, handle the `onload` event.

You can expose this in a wrapper function which takes a function as a parameter, and calls it if jQuery has been loaded, or puts it in an array (to call in the load handler) if it's not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

An old-school answer :)
You can create a recursive polling function that check to see if the $ object exists eg:

```
function poller(){
    if($.length != 0){
       //do what you want

    }else{
       setTimeout(poller, 100);
    }    
}
```

And right after you load the jQuery script run the poller function.