# Set JavaScript variable to check definition later

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can you set a var to something you want to later check if it's defined or not?

Example:  To check if jQuery is not defined, you'd do this:

```
if (typeof(jQuery) === 'undefined') { 
}
```

But what if I want to do something like this (this obviously doesn't work):

```
   var toCheckLater = jQuery;   // This fails.

   // Some time later.. 
   if (typeof(toCheckLater) === 'undefined') {
   }
```

What I'm trying to do is dynamically load scripts from an array, but I want to set ahead of time the variable whose definition I'll check for later.  And I'd like to avoid a big block of ifs or switch statement.  Meaning I'm hoping to find a solution a bit more elegant than:

```
switch (scriptName) {
  case 'jQuery': 
    if (typeof(jQuery) === 'undefined') {
    }
    break;
  case 'someOtherScriptName':
  .
  .
  .
}
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function would do:

```
var toCheckLater = function() { return typeof jQuery == "undefined"; }

// later:
toCheckLater()
```

You might also use a fabric for such functions:

```
function getChecker(name) {
    return function() {
        return typeof window[name] == "undefined";
        // alternative:
        return name in window; // can be undefined, but the variable exists
    };
}
var toCheckLater = getChecker("jQuery");
```

Comment: Damn, so simple... I can't believe I didn't think of setting it as a function.  I'm very disappointed with myself (and others who answered without reading the question), but very happy with your help.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to follow up... the function approach worked better for me, because I'm also checking typeof($.receiveMessage).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (typeof jQuery === "undefined")
```

to check for undefined.

Comment: That doesn't help.  I did however forget the typeof part, so I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you're trying to achieve, but I think you could do something like this

```
var toCheckLater = typeof jQuery; //if, for example, jQuery is defined you'll get "function"

// Some time later.. 
if (toCheckLater === 'undefined') {

}
```

Comment: I want to check if it's defined later.  Your suggestion would check if defined right away and then give me an old value later.

Comment: Aww ok, I understood (a little late :P). I hope I was able to help a bit anyways

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
var scriptName = 'jQuery';

if( !window.hasOwnProperty(scriptName) ){
    //jQuery is undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var checker = function(scriptArray) {
  for(var i in scriptArray) 
    this[i] = i?i:loadScript(i); // make your own loadScript function
}

checker({'jquery','anothercode'});

//access checker.jquery / checker.anothercode
```

You could use something like this. Create a 'class' that load all the scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You have use the `typeof` Method

`typeof(variable_name)` will give you "string",  "object", "undefined" or "number" depending on the variable

```
typeof(jQuery) == "undefined"
```

is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your array of scripts:

```
var scripts = ['script1', 'jQuery'];
```

After loading the scripts you can use the same array and loop through it.

```
for (var i = 0, n = scripts.length; i !== n; i++) {
    if (!window.scripts[i]) {
        // falsy
    }
}
```

This assumes that the scripts array references a global variable that the script will expose when loaded.

However, if I understand what you're going for, a better method would be to register a callback for when the appropriate `script` element is loaded. See these questions  for some examples: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249030/load-javascript-async-then-check-dom-loaded-before-executing-callback), [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032721/async-load-javascript-files-with-callback)

Code like this is pretty standard:

```
function loadScriptAsync(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script'),
        place = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.async = true;
    script.src = src;
    script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function() {
        callback();
        // clean up for IE and Opera
        script.onload = null;
        script.onreadystatechange = null;
    };

    place.parentNode.insertBefore(script, place);
}
```