# Asynchronous Script Loading Callback

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, callback

> http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/HQDu6/

I've created a short function based on [Mathias Bynens Optimization of the Google Analytics asynchronous script](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/async-analytics-snippet) that goes as following:

```
function async(src) {
  var d = document, t = 'script',
      o = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  o.src = '//' + src;
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(o, s);
}
```

This works great and I've already started using it for several different scripts

```
// Crazy Egg
async('dnn506yrbagrg.cloudfront.net/pages/scripts/XXXXX/XXXXX.js?' + Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 3600000));

// User Voice
var uvOptions = {};
async('widget.uservoice.com/XXXXX.js');

// Google Analytics
var _gaq = [['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXX-XX'], ['_setDomainName', 'coachup.com'], ['_trackPageview']];
async('google-analytics.com/ga.js');

// Stripe
async('js.stripe.com/v1');​
```

The problem comes when I encounter a script that needs to be called after it's loaded:

```
// Snap Engage
async('snapabug.appspot.com/snapabug.js');
SnapABug.init('XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX');
```

So I figured I'd turn this into a callback function that would be used as so:

```
async('snapabug.appspot.com/snapabug.js', function() {
    SnapABug.init('XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX');
});
```

I did not expect that this would be difficult for me to do but it has turned out that way.

#### My question is what is the most efficient way to add a callback without overcomplicating the code.

> See the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/HQDu6/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3211647/982924 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/4249346/982924

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Thanks [RASG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/982924/rasg) for https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211647/982924

#### Async function with callback:

```
function async(u, c) {
  var d = document, t = 'script',
      o = d.createElement(t),
      s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  o.src = '//' + u;
  if (c) { o.addEventListener('load', function (e) { c(null, e); }, false); }
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(o, s);
}
```

Usage:

```
async('snapabug.appspot.com/snapabug.js', function() {
    SnapABug.init('XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX-XXXXX');
});
```

> [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesKyle/wvBKq/)

Comment: The line `o.u = '//' + u;` should read `o.src = '//' + u;` or else it won't load a single byte. Minifying can be tricky at times.

Comment: s.addEventListener should be o.addEventListener

Comment: I think this needs more logic to deal with IE8 and before, see for example: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/prevent-double-callback-execution-in-IE9

Comment: I think this solution is more comprehensive and includes a `Promise` implementation too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718935/load-scripts-asynchronously

Answer (score 14):

A more recent snippet:

```
async function loadAsync(src) {
    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (script.readyState === 'loaded' || script.readyState === 'complete') {
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
                resolve(true);
            }
        };
        document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    });
}
```

utilisation

```
  loadAsync(`https://....js`).then(_ => {
    //  ... script loaded here
  })
```

---

[James Kyle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12821561/247696) doesn't take IE9 into account. Here is a modified version of the code I found [in the link proposed in the comments](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/prevent-double-callback-execution-in-IE9). Modify the var baseUrl so it can find the script accordingly.

```
//for requiring a script loaded asynchronously.
function loadAsync(src, callback, relative){
    var baseUrl = "/resources/script/";
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    if(relative === true){
        script.src = baseUrl + src;  
    }else{
        script.src = src; 
    }

    if(callback !== null){
        if (script.readyState) { // IE, incl. IE9
            script.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (script.readyState === "loaded" || script.readyState === "complete") {
                    script.onreadystatechange = null;
                    callback();
                }
            };
        } else {
            script.onload = function() { // Other browsers
                callback();
            };
        }
    }
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
```

utilisation:

```
loadAsync('https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js' , function(){
    chart.loadCharts();
    });
// OR relative path
loadAsync('fastclick.js', null, true);
```

Comment: Nice work & thanks for the great answer. Just change "doc" in the last line of the function to "document".

Answer (score 12):

The other answers works well, but aren't super readable or require Promises. Here is my two cents:

```
function loadScript(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('src', src);
    script.addEventListener('load', callback);
    document.head.appendChild(script);
},
```

Comment: Small improvement: If you use `script.addEventListener('load', callback,{ once: true });` then the listener will be cleared automatically after the load event has fired.