# Problems in synchronous javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am learning javascript and want to use synchronous javascript call in my code.

For example i have two scripts, script1.js and script2.js. Here is script1.js:

```
<script>

var value1="Script 1";
alert(value1);

//calling script2
url="script2.js"
document.write("<scr" + "ipt src=\"" + url + "\"></scr" + "ipt>");

</script>
```

Here is script2.js

```
  <script>       
    var value2="Script 2";       
    </script>
```

Now my question is can i print value from script2 like if i add this( alert(value2);) in my script1.js.

```
<script>

var value1="Script 1";
alert(value1);

//calling script2
url="script2.js"
document.write("<scr" + "ipt src=\"" + url + "\"></scr" + "ipt>");
alert(value2);
</script>
```

I have done this using asychronous js as

```
 var scr = document.createElement('script');
 scr.setAttribute('src', url);
 var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
 head.appendChild(scr);
```

It is working but i want to achieve this synchronously any suggestions??

Thanks in advance

Comment: someone gave me -1? why i am learning javascript may be it is a very simple question for many but i am confused in this one i just need explanation

Comment: script open tag is `<script>` and closing tag is `</script>`

Comment: oh thanks i have updated this one.

Comment: *"Now my question is can i print value from script2 like if i add this( alert(value2);) in my script1.js."* did you try running the code? what was the outcome?

Comment: Why are you calling your second approach asynchronous? It's also synchronous. A better description is using DOM manipulation

Comment: If you're looking to import lots of scripts you can look into a script loading framework like the following http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/for-your-script-loading-needs--net-19570

Comment: Poor form downvoting beginners!

Comment: What is the purpose of this task? What are you trying to do? why are you doing it? it seems rather pointless.

Comment: funny some one is voting -1 to all the answers

Comment: 2/3 of the answers are avoiding the question entirely and answering something else instead, so they're rightfully downvoted.

Comment: i am writing some code and its the requorement to use inline or appendhead* . Appendhead is working while adding inline using document.write is having a problem and this is just a test case of what i am doing

Comment: @user3754674 Are you sure you tried what I suggested? Read my answer carefully and try again, it works on my machine

Answer (score 0):

When adding a script  like you did in the first case, you can only use values from inside script2.js after you open a new script tag.

**index.html**

```
<script>
var value1="Script 1";
alert(value1);

//calling script2
url="script2.js"
document.write("<scr" + "ipt src='script2.js'></scr" + "ipt>");
</script>
<script>
alert(value2);
</script>
```

**script2.js**

```
var value2='yes';
```

Tested locally and verified that it does work (I see an alert with 'yes'), and what you have (all in the same script tag) does not work (throws an exception because value2 is undefined).

Comment: what does it mean can you explain in detail ?

Comment: do you mean adding  document.write("<script>"); before calling script2.js?

Comment: No, another script tag. `</script><script> do stuff here!`

Comment: still value2 is undefined

Comment: @KevinB i added this document.write("<scr" + "ipt></scr" + "ipt>"); after calling sciptt2.js and still not working

Comment: that's not at all what i suggested. i was clarifying @JuanMendes's suggestion, which he just made clearer with an example.

Comment: @user3754674 I just tested this on my local machine (in IE10 and Chrome) and the findings are exactly as I expected, the code you have fails because value2 is not defined and, what I posted does correctly alert the value of value2, you must not be doing what I suggested. Downvoters, you should explain why you downvoted

Comment: thanks but this is not my solution as i am not using script1.js in the index html but all script files are external

Answer (score -1):

In javascript, the order of the scripts is always synchronous. Because you added script 2 after initialization, you created a DOM that looks like this.

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
        //script 1
      </script>
   </head>
   <body> 
      ---Body content here
   </body>
</html>
<script src="script2.js"/>
```

Note how you put the script at the end of the page. Because the HTML is read synchronously, script1 will finish executing (including the alert() which will have value2 be undefined because script2 hasn't been parsed yet), then the HTML body will be processed, then script2.js.

If you wish to load a secondary script synchronously in the middle of your current script, you will have to do an `XMLHTTPRequest` and get the content, then run `eval(script_2_content)`. Eval will in place compile and parse the second script, synchronously.

What you would then be doing is:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script>
        //script 1 before loading script 2
        //script 2 content
        //script 1 content after loading script 2
      </script>
   </head>
   <body> 
      ---Body content here
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? That was my understanding of how HTML parsers work.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you want an [asynchronous function, with a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820953/asynchronous-script-loading-callback). (The first answer, shows your example exactly!).

Basically, when the function has finished loading your script, it will call the callback function, where you should be able to run your `alert(value2);` script.

Otherwise, if you want to use document.write, you have these options:

(I think the problem is, the `<script></script>` tags in your *.js files, they're not required!)

**src1.js**

```
document.write('<script src="src2.js"></script'+'>');
document.write('<script>alert(value2);</script'+'>');
```

**src2.js**

```
var value2 = 'foobar!'
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="src1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does this meet your requirements?

Comment: i want to do it inline using document.write