# Defer execution until external script has loaded in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, dom-events, recaptcha

I want to render a `recaptcha` after a `Vue.js` component has mounted. It works on normal load and reload, but when I navigate away to a different `url` and click the browser back button it throws an error.

Here is my setup:

- I am loading the `api` script at the bottom of the page:

  `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js' async></script>`
- on that page I render a globally registered component called `Contact.vue` that contains a local component called `Recaptcha.vue`:

  `<app-recaptcha @recaptchaResponse="updateRecaptchaResponse"></app-recaptcha>`

The code for `Recaptcha.vue` looks like this:

```
<template>
    <div id="app-recaptcha">
        <div :id="placeholderId"></div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                sitekey: 'key_here',
                placeholderId: 'grecaptcha',
                widgetId: null
            }
        },


        mounted() {
            this.$nextTick(function () {
                this.render();
            });
        },


        methods: {
            render() {
                this.widgetId = window.grecaptcha.render(this.placeholderId, {
                    sitekey: this.sitekey,
                    callback: (response) => {
                        this.$emit('recaptchaResponse', response);
                    }
                });
            },

            reset() {
                window.grecaptcha.reset(this.widgetId);
            }
        }
    }
</script>


<style>...</style>
```

On normal page load/ reload `this.render()` is executed normally. However, when I navigate to another `url` and return via the back button I get: `Error in nextTick: "TypeError: window.grecaptcha.render is not a function"`.

I tried to:

- set a variable on the `onload` event of the `api` script:

  `<script src='...' onload="window.script = { recaptcha: 'ready' }" async></script>`
- then add it as a property in `data()` of `Recaptcha.vue`:

  `ready: window.script.recaptcha`
- next, I added a watcher on the `ready` property and within that watcher I tried to run `this.render()`

No success, the error is still there. I think that even in the normal load/ reload situation I am simply "lucky" that the `api` script loads before the component gets mounted, and that placing `this.render()` inside the `mounted()` hook isn't helpful.

Do you know how can I signal `Recaptcha.vue` that the external script has finished loading, and only then render the `recaptcha`?

Comment: it is usually only use `async` or `defer` not both at same time.

Comment: Corrected that, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asynchronous Script Loading Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820953/asynchronous-script-loading-callback)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but that doesn't really answer my question. I would prefer a simpler way to just signal the component that the script has loaded.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

okay, here's a theory: add data properties

```
captchaReady: false, 
checkingInterval: null,
```

created

```
let localThis = this 
this.checkingInterval = setInterval(function(){
  if (window.grecaptcha) {
    localThis.captchaReady = true
  }
}, 500) //or whatever interval you want to check
```

Then

```
watch: {
  captchaReady: function(data) {
    if (data) { 
       clearInterval(this.checkingInterval) 
       this.render()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It looks interesting, I am trying it now! What is the `data` parameter for in `captchaReady: function(data)`?

Comment: watch functions take a parameter that is the value of the property being watched. In the (Vue docs they call it `val`) -
 so `if (data)` means `if (this.captchaReady === true)` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-vs-Watched-Property

Comment: Ah, totally forgot that. It works and it is pretty ingenious. Marked as accepted. Cheers!