# Callback function after script Algolia places.js is loaded

Tags: algolia

I don't want to put this script tag in the header of my html:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.7.3"></script>
```

The main reason is the block that would cause on loading the entire page.

I want to load the script thus:

```
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/places.js@1.7.3';
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

and I would like can add **?callback=init_input** to the js URL to initialize, after places.js was loaded completely, the input element. Is possible?

I know this option is available in Google Maps API but I don't want use it.

Thank you,

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is not specific to Algolia Places or Google Maps but on how to load a script asynchronously and have a callback. It is answered on SO already: [Asynchronous Script Loading Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12820953/asynchronous-script-loading-callback)