# Select elements dynamically loaded

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I'm facing a issue getting dynamically loaded elements in the dom that I cannot find the right answer to solve this issue.

Let's say I have an MVC architecture where I load all my views into a container div.

So I load a view which also has a ul element, now I create multiples li dynamically and when I call.

```
 ul = document.getElementById("idelement");
```

I get undefined, even if the view is already loaded.

I tried using, (document).ready, event delegation on(load), among other techniques and I cannot find the rigth solution for this.

Any advices?

Comment: If `document.getElementById` can't find it, it is not in your DOM.

Comment: do you have a callback for when all your dom is loaded?

Comment: it is in there, cause I can see it on the inspector and it is perfectly loaded. And no, I do not have a callback, however the element inside the view which are not dynamically loaded display perfectly

Comment: Can you demonstrate this problem with a ([minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or similar, demo?

Comment: sadly, I cannot, there is a lot of code to display.

Comment: but is it perfectly loaded when your code executes?  Sure sounds like it isn't

Comment: Hence 'minimal,' reduce your problem to the *simplest*, *smallest* demonstration of the problem (without the accompanying cruft). If you can't do that, then I'm unsure how we can help.

Comment: well it is, it does not drop any errors, and I only cannot see the dynamic elements, however if I console.log the variables that supposes to add the elements, it display the right element, it is just not inserting them

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I came out with [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032721/async-load-javascript-files-with-callback) , it looks like a chrome bug, the solution I found was to set a timeout of 500ms as the article says.