# Prevent jQuery.getScript adding ?_=timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to prevent `jQuery.getScript` from adding `?_=timestamp` on URLs?

[image: error log]

Source code:

```
$.getScript('/js/ace/ace.js',function(res) {
   // do something
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I made another aprouch using promises, based on previous responses, think that's more interesting.

```
window.loadScripts = (scripts) =>  {
    return scripts.reduce((currentPromise, scriptUrl) => {
        return currentPromise.then(() => {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                var script = document.createElement('script');
                script.async = true;
                script.src = scriptUrl;
                script.onload = () => resolve();
                document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
            });
        });
    }, Promise.resolve());
};
```

Let's play

```
var scripts = [
    "app/resources/scriptDoSomething.js",
    "app/resources/somethingElse.js"
];

loadScripts(scripts).then(() => {
  alert('All scripts were loaded!');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

This seems to be related to `$.getScript('/js/ace/ace.js',function...)` calls.

You can consider adding the following snippet as high up as possible:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: true
});
```

Putting the cache: `true` in your `$.ajax()` doesn't affect `$.getScript('/js/ace/ace.js',function...)`
in any way and that's what visible in that screenshot.

Another way, as described at [jQueryByExample](http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/use-jquerygetscript-to-load-external-js.html):

**(1)** before making call to `$.getScript` method, you can set the cache true for ajax request and set it to false once script is loaded.

```
//Code Starts
//Set Cache to true.
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
$.getScript(urlhere, function(){
    //call the function here....
    //Set cache to false.
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
//Code Ends
```

**(2)** All you need to do is to add a `boolean` parameter, which will set the cache attribute to true or false. That's the beauty of `jQuery` that you can redefine things the way you need.

```
//Code Starts
$.getScript = function(url, callback, cache){
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url,
    success: callback,
    dataType: "script",
    cache: cache
    });
};
```

So,now you call the `$.getScript` like, (notice the 3rd argument)

```
//Code Starts
$.getScript('js/jsPlugin.js',function(){
   Demo(); //This function is placed in jsPlugin.js
}, true);
//Code Ends
```

Comment: @Kokizzu, check another couple of solutions

Comment: ah wait, it works, previously I misread the `$.ajaxSetup` as `$.ajax`

Comment: Plagiarism: copied without attribution from http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/04/use-jquerygetscript-to-load-external-js.html

Comment: @Pekka웃, answered this long back, when was not aware of proper practice. Edited post.. mark words, it was not intentional! thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I made my own `getScript` based on [Caolan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3211647/1620210)'s answer:

```
H = H || {};

// load a script and run a callback
H.loadScript = function(src, callback) {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = src;
    script.addEventListener('load', function (e) { H.ExecIfFunction(callback,e); }, false);
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    head.appendChild(script);
};

// sources is array, the load process is serial
H.loadScripts = function(sources, callback) {
    var len = sources.length;
    var now = 0;
    var loadOne = function() {
        if(now < len) return H.loadScript(sources[now++],loadOne);
        if(now >= len) H.ExecIfFunction(callback);
    };
    loadOne();
};
```

Usage example:

```
H.loadScripts(['/js/ace/ace.js','/js/ace/mode-json.js','/js/jquery-ace.js'],function(){
  // do something
});
```

Those function doesn't check if any of script loading is unsuccessful.